# Inequality on the sum of an abstract complex power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I needed to show that if a$ \displaystyle\sum c_nz^n$ has a convergence radius $R>0$ then the one of $\displaystyle\sum \dfrac{c_nz^n}{n!}$ is infinite and that its sum $f(z)$ follows $\forall 0<\theta<1 \;\exists M(\theta)\geq0$ such as $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq M(\theta)e^{\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{\theta R}}$.

I did the first part all right but i can't seem to get the right inequality for the sum $f(z)$

Comment: In first series $\lim_\infty\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\dfrac{1}{R}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses: how do you get that the limit even exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement about the radius of convergence guarantees that for any $\epsilon\gt0$,
$$
|c_n|\le\frac{a_\epsilon(1+\epsilon)^n}{R^n}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{c_nz^n}{n!}\right|
&\le a_\epsilon\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{1+\epsilon}R|z|\right)^n\\
&\le a_\epsilon e^{\frac{1+\epsilon}R|z|}
\end{align}
$$
Set $\epsilon=\frac1\theta-1$.

Comment: Never seen such reasonning for problems like this one but that's really nice. What if i use Cauchy's formula ? I get $ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\lvert \dfrac{c^n}{n!}z^n \rvert\leq \displaystyle\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{s^n}\,\underset{\lvert z \rvert =s}{\max} \,f(z) \dfrac{\lvert z\rvert ^n}{n!} = \underset{\lvert z \rvert =s}{\max} \,f(z)  e^{\frac{\vert z \vert}{s}}$ and since $s<R$ i say that $\theta$ is the number such as $\theta R=s$. Does that work ?

Comment: Rob, the terms $c_n$ are complex in general.  And even if they're real, they could be negative.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I have added the absolute values that I forgot before.