# a bound of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Question**
let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be a power series with radius $R$, show that $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} z^n$ is an entire function and there exist a constant $M$ such that$|g(z)|\le Me^{\frac{|z|}{R}}$.

**My attempt**
It is easily to compute $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]\frac{|a_n|}{n!}=0$. For the second statement, I note $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n!}|z|^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|R^n \frac{w^n}{n!}$, where $w=\frac{|z|}{R}$.So my last aim is to show $|a_n|R^n$ is a bound sequence.

How do I reach this idea?

Comment: This looks similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2167131/42969

Comment: Is it really true? If $a_n=n/R^{n-1}$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ is a power series with radius $R$, but $g(z)=ze^{z/R}$ cannot be bounded by a constant multiple of $e^{|z|/R}$.

Comment: The result should be that the bound holds for the exponent $(1+\epsilon)/R$ in general; only when $|a_nR^n|$ bounded, the inequality holds as stated

Comment: thank you! From your example, I find $|a_n|R^n$ is not a bounded sequences generally and this problem may be a incorrect.